# How to refresh displayed date in CalendarExtender?

Tags: asp.net, calendarextender

I've this code that changes the maximum date of a second Calendar Extender to 90 days after the date that has been defined in a first one and minimum to the same it has been selected on the first and it works right except for one thing.

```
            var cal2 = $find("calendar2");
            var fecha = cal._selectedDate;

            var date = fecha.getDate() + 90;
            var year = fecha.getFullYear();
            var month = fecha.getMonth();

            var todayDate = new Date(year, month, date);


            cal2._startDate = cal._selectedDate;
            cal2._selectedDate = fecha;
            cal2._switchMonth(fecha);
            cal2._endDate = todayDate;
```

Problem is that if I first seelct a date on cal, dates are properly shown in cal2, but I select one on cal again then cal2 doesn't display in the same month that cal, what's much worse it displays to select days that would be now impossible to select and in fact you can select them unless you go back first to month mode.

Any idea on how to "refresh" the behavior of the second CalendarExtender?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain this is being properly called on the second change? Just to clarify you are setting the second calendar to the date selected in the first and limiting its range to 90 days, correct? Is this the code in calendar one client click?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method.

```js
Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype.refresh = function () {
        this._isOpen = true;
        this._ensureCalendar();
        this.invalidate();
        this._isOpen = false;
    }
```

When you add the method only call:

```js
cal2.refresh()
```

Comment: Can you translate your answer into English?  You can edit your answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site. Please post in English. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/1402846) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) for details. Thank you.